# An upper bound of the form $A\cdot n\log n$ for the $n$th prime number

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

It is well known that if $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number, then
$$p_n>n\log n$$
and in fact, $p_n\sim n\log n$. I wanted to flip this inequality. That is, I wanted to find a real number $A$ such that
$$p_n<A\cdot n\log n$$
From my calculations, $A$ should be greater than $1$, but less than $2$ (remember, as small as possible). I calculated the value of $A$ to be less than $1.33$. But, my computer is not much fast, so I couldn't find the smallest possible $A$. And note that $p_n<1.33n\log n$ doesn't work for all $n$, but it (probably) works for all $n>40000$. So my question is, is it true that
$$p_n<1.33\,n\log n\quad\forall n>40000$$
and if yes, how can it be proved?
This inequality is indeed very good; since 1 is very near to 1.33. Any help would be appreciated.
**Update**: Weakening the bounds from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) article gives
$$p_n<1.37n\log n$$
I don't know if this would help, but a somewhat related procedure can probably prove this.

Comment: [This paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL22/Axler/axler17.pdf) has some results you should check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $(1.7)$ in the paper cited by @JimmyK4542, it follows that
$$
p_n  < 1.1756\cdot n\log n
$$
for all $n\geq 40000$. In fact, it also follows that
$$
p_n  < 1.2232\cdot n\log n
$$
for all $n\geq 20$.